# How to easily recognize searched item in a dense QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsScene` with many `QGraphicsItem` like `circle`, `rectangle`, `polylines`, `arc` etc.
Every `QGraphicsItem` has a name. And I have a `Search` feature which highlights searched items using that name.  When `scene` contains fewer items, highlighted items are seen properly. But when `scene` contains many items ( 100 + ) then identifying the highlighted item becomes difficult. For that I need to scroll up - down or left - right to check where is that highlighted item is.

> So I want my highlighted item to be easily recognizable.

For that I was suggested, some approach like

- Take searched item in front
  Or
- Add some marker

But I do not know, how to implement it , which Qt class should I use etc.

Comment: could you add screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphicsScene` displays items depending on their stacking, i.e., when you call `.items()`, the first item in the `QList` is the topmost item on the scene.

The ordering of the items is depending on their respective Z-values which you can set for the `QGraphicsItem` by calling `.setZValue()`

You can read more about this on the following link: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#sorting

As for your question on how to put them in front. If you implemented your own children classes of `QGraphicsItem`, you can add a method or a slot to toggle them "on-top". E.g., all of the items usually have a Z-order of 0, so your method could just set it to 1 when the item is highlighted and revert it to 0 when it's not.